# Get Property from QML file to .py file

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I am using PySide2, Qt Quick, and Qt Creator.
I am trying to make it so that it uses a variable from the text field that is stored in the QML file and run a command that prints the variable into the console using print().

In the main.py file, I created this code that finds the price of assets of cryptocurrencies.

```
def assetSet(self):
    asset = "xrp"
    url2 = f'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/{asset}'
    page2 = requests.get(url2)
    soup2 = bs(page2.text, 'html.parser')
    price2 = soup2.find(class_="priceValue___11gHJ")
    price12 = str(price2)
    result2 = re.search('<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">(.*)</div>', price12)
    result12 = result2.group(1)
    self.setAsset.emit(f"The price of {asset} is {result12}")
```

In the QML File, I have

```
            CustomButton{
                id: btnBdo
                text: "Check"
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 200
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 0
                font.pointSize: 20
                colorMouseOver: "#21252d"
                colorPressed: "#191d23"
                colorDefault: "#2a303a"
                onClicked: {
                    backend.assetSet()
                }
            }
            CustomTextField {
                id: textField
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: -100
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                font.pointSize: 20
                placeholderText: qsTr("Enter a name")
                objectName: "assetField"
            }
```

I want the asset variable to equal the text field that is stored in the QML file and run this command when the button is clicked.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is best to use a slot that receives the data, and since the execution of the function is also synchronous then the signal is not necessary:

```py
@Slot(str, result=str)
def assetSet(self, asset):
    url2 = f'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/{asset}'
    page2 = requests.get(url2)
    soup2 = bs(page2.text, 'html.parser')
    price2 = soup2.find(class_="priceValue___11gHJ")
    price12 = str(price2)
    result2 = re.search('<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">(.*)</div>', price12)
    result12 = result2.group(1)
    return f"The price of {asset} is {result12}"
```

```
onClicked: function(){
    var resp = backend.assetSet(textField.text)
    console.log(resp)
}
```

---

On the other hand, the request can block the Qt event loop causing the GUI to freeze so it is better to execute that task in another thread:

```py
from functools import cached_property
import os.path
import re
import sys
import threading

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Qt, QUrl, Signal, Slot
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = Signal(str)

    def start(self, asset):
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, args=(asset,), daemon=True).start()

    def _execute(self, asset):
        url2 = f"https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/{asset}"
        page2 = requests.get(url2)
        soup2 = bs(page2.text, "html.parser")
        price2 = soup2.find(class_="priceValue___11gHJ")
        price12 = str(price2)
        result2 = re.search('<div class="priceValue___11gHJ">(.*)</div>', price12)
        if result2 is not None:
            result12 = result2.group(1)
            self.finished.emit(f"The price of {asset} is {result12}")
            return
        self.finished.emit(f"failed for {asset}")


class Backend(QObject):
    assetChanged = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.assetChanged)

    @cached_property
    def worker(self):
        return Worker()

    @Slot(str)
    def assetSet(self, asset):
        self.worker.start(asset)


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    backend = Backend()

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", backend)

    CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    file = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    engine.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Column {
        Button {
            id: button

            text: "Press me"
            onClicked: function() {
                backend.assetSet(textField.text);
            }
        }

        TextField {
            id: textField

            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter a name")
        }

        Label {
            id: label
        }

    }

    Connections {
        function onAssetChanged(asset) {
            label.text = asset;
        }

        target: backend
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! If it is fine with you, can you explain what this is doing? I'm still new to python and want to learn as much as I can. Thank you again!

Comment: Oh ok got it. Thank you for the link, I will read over it! Also, when I start up the app, there is an warning saying:

.../qml/pages/homePage.qml:171:5: QML Connections: Detected function "onAssetChanged" in Connections element. This is probably intended to be a signal handler but no signal of the target matches the name. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Yes, I wrote the code you provided for me word for word.

Comment: @Final_Software I do not have this error message: 1) I am assuming that you are using the latest versions of the libraries, 2) Try my complete demo (do not put it in your project code as your code may have other errors), 3 ) If my demo works then the problem is in your project code and unfortunately I will not be able to help you with it.

Comment: Sorry, it worked when I put it on the top part of the code. Thank you

Comment: @Final_Software So I asked you if you had placed the code as it is, you said yes and you made me waste my time creating the complete demo, please take the time of others seriously. On the other hand, check the [tour] so you know what to do when an answer solves your problem.